# what is the equevalant for getelementbyid in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

javascript code...

```
<div>
<canvas #layout width="800" height="600">this is not working</canvas>
code here...
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("layout")
}
```

in angular
app.component.html...

```
<canvas #layout width="800" height="600">this is not working</canvas>
```

app.component.ts...

```
@ViewChild('layout') canvas;
 ngOnInit() {

  const _canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
  ....
  }
```

Comment: what is the different between viewChild and the .nativeElemet

Comment: viewChild returns ElementRef object, nativeElement is a DOM object